# Google Data studio/looker aggregate question

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I've been having this type of question for quite a while and every time when I get back I can't seem to find a solution.

So what I'm trying to achieve in looker is to use in a formula an aggregated value. Something like a SUMIFS in Google Sheet.

For example this is the data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2J1e.png)

What I'm looking for is to use the Total Revenue
PER Project
PER Year Month
in a formula for each row.

In our case the total for Project P1 Year Month 2023 01 is 220.

Using aggregated values in custom fields in data studio is not possible from what I know.

So an equivalent in Google Sheets would be SUMIFS( Sum Amount, Criteria range Year Month, Criteria row 1 for example, Criteria range Project, Criteria row 1)

That would create a new column, and each row (depending on these 2 criteria Year Month and Project) will have 220.

Another example could be for expenses where a new column would have the total expenses at -140. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DTM7.png)

Answer (score 0):

(Possible) Solution:

- Only show columns: YearMonth and Project
- Aggregate the amount by using SUM(IF([Type]="Revenue" THEN [AMOUNT] ELSE 0)) For Revenue, and change the logic for the expense